# Best practices for path-agnostic links in Django?

Tags: django

What is the best way to code html links in a Django application
which is intended to be distributed to other users and
where it cannot be known in advance what the final
URL path to the application will be?

Here are some links I am currently using:

```
<li><a href="/results/all_runs/">By Date</a></li>
<li><a href="/results/trends/by_app">Trends</a></li>
```

This works fine when the app is configured like this in mysite/urls.py to
be in the root path.

```
url(r'^', include('myapp.urls')),
```

But if you change mysite/urls.py to run the app in a different path:

```
url(r'^myapp/', include('myapp.urls')),
```

then the links break.  This seems like it ought to be a common scenario but I have been unable to discover how to solve it cleanly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) tag:

> Returns an absolute path reference (a URL without the domain name) matching a given view function and optional parameters. This is a way to output links without violating the DRY principle by having to hard-code URLs in your templates